# What was Flash referring to at the end of the last episode of Justice League Unlimited?

Tags: dc, the-flash, dc-animated-universe, justice-league-unlimited

I just rewatched the entire series on Netflix, and something is bothering me. Its what Flash says at the end.

His last line is "these are the end times", delivered with a complete blank look on his face... What is he referring to?

Answer (score 12):

Right before Flash says, "These are the end times," he sees Martian Manhunter call his wife.  J'onn tells her he'll be back in time for dinner and that he loves her.  That's what Flash is referring to.  He's making a joke about the Martian Manhunter's new human life.

Comment: I battled with myself if I should include this **TV-Tropes-Link** - so follow at your own peril: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SignOfTheApocalypse [as of right now the last entry on that page].

Comment: @BMWurm There's nothing wrong with TV Tropes. Please quit acting like it's a site that hands out computer viruses.

Comment: @TylerH I know that, in fact it's  a great place, but there is also this: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5133/30726